# What languages and technologies are used to make professional video editors like Adobe Premiere Pro and Davinci Resolve?

Tags: video, adobe, video-processing, davinci

Most professional video editors have features like color grading, motion capture, object tracking, video manipulation. What technologies are behind these functions?

As far as I've researched, most video editing software use C++. Is there any resource where I might learn to create one professional video editor by myself? I know Python and C++.

Need resources or guides to make a professional video editor.

Comment: **(1)** As well as a fast language like C++ (or Assembly) they usually utilize GPU technology for fast crunching of large numbers (_eg:_ pixels for multiple frames). You don't need a "technology" to color grade. Just adjust the RGB values of your pixel array. If you've never handled basic RGB data, and it's all a mystery to you (bytes, hues, luminosity, etc), then don't jump to creating a video editor... **(2)** If you can create a user interface then maybe a library like FFmpeg can be useful to you to modify the pixels (video manipulation). Try OpenCV for object tracking...

Comment: **PS:** Most likely your question will be closed since it simply asks for recommendations. You need to show a testable code problem first, then it's okay if the answer is itself a software recommendation.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind. Also, do you have any recommendations for technologies for making a web-based video editor (not as advanced as Adobe or Davinci, but a simple one)?

Comment: Not sure what a "simple" editor is about... You mean like 2 text boxes for the Start and End times and then a button labelled as "Trim video"? Anyways... There are APIs in HTML5/JS (both work together) for handling video, sound and pixels and arrays. There is a GPU also if you want to go there (is advanced but usable). The most important API is WebCodecs since it will allow you to encode into a browser-compatible format (_eg:_ as VP9 for webM, or as H264 for MP4). You still need to know how to work with RGB data, how to write or delete byte values (is numbers inside an array), etc..

Comment: Okay. I understand now. Thanks for you time!

Comment: By the way... **(1)** JS has ability to run some C++ code in browser (using WebAssembly). **(2)** My advice would be to **practice** on HTML5/JS since it gives faster feedback (_eg:_ no compiling, just refresh the browser to see new code changes). Also there, it is easier to create a visual interface (using HTML5), modify (byte) arrays without pointers as needed in C++, also you can read or change pixel colours easily as RGBA data array (for colour grading).  **(3)** It's going to be a lot of work. Some edits can be done by editing bytes (eg: trimming, rotation, etc) and some need pixel edits.

Comment: PS: A long time ago I made [this demo](https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/vc1.clients.lutprev1/demo_lut_previewer_vc1_01.html) for someone. It uses GPU for a fast updating of colours per frame. Just a basic example to show you that the beginnings of a video editor is possible using technologies like HTML / JS / GPU processing, etc etc... PPS: Demo is just a basic previewer of the code result, the interface did not matter (only that the video colours change). The next step could be to output those edited pixels as new video using WebCodecs API. I don't know what the client did with it.

Comment: Also check [VidMix](https://vidmix.app/) and also [Clideo](https://clideo.com/editor/video-maker) for inspiration about HTML5 based video editors. If they are similar to what you want then you know its feasible in HTML5... I don't think the "what technologies" can be answered. You can only use API's since a file is bytes (Arrays API, Math API) and you get picture (so use Canvas API) and sound (so use Audio API), then you modify the audio/video data with math, then save output with WebCodecs API and File API). There are tutorials and algorithms on the web towards building any effects you need.

Comment: Damn, that's really helpful. Thank you so much. Sorry for the late reply.